# How can I make GET variables look like a path?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have a URL that looks like this: `http://example.com/board?b=utst` (there are a couple variations of similar URLs). However, I want it to look like this: `http://example.com/board/utst/`. How would I go about doing this? I haven't tried much, but I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: it's called a mod rewrite

Comment: Search for ["URL rewrite"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+url+rewrite). There are no shortages of examples online; or similar questions. (Code would generate the pretty URL and, upon a request, mod_rewrite turns the pretty URL back into the 'ugly URL' which is processed by PHP.)

Comment: awesome, thank you both!

Comment: Please post ur comment as answer. It's worth. Tnx